# Run EnumProperty's update on animation keyframe change

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script that a adds a dropdown menu that I want to later animate the values of. In the update of the EnumProperty I update some visibility filters depending on the item selected which works fine when flipping through the items in the drop down, but when I animate the value and it changes that way the "update" doesn't get called. Can I make it so it does?

Here is an example script

```
import bpy


class MYOBJECT_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "My Object"
    bl_idname = "MYOBJECT_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "My Object"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "MyObjectList")


def print_to_console(scene, context):
    print(context.scene.MyObjectList)


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.MyObjectList = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="My Objects",
        items=[(x, x, "") for x in ["A", "B", "C"]],
        update=print_to_console
    )
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYOBJECT_PT_Panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MYOBJECT_PT_Panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.MyObjectList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Then go into animate and key the property and scrub the frames, you can see that the print state ment doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved a similar functionality by adding a handler to [`bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre). This will make the `print_to_console` print every frame I can then check "is the gui displaying the same value as the previous frame", and if not it is animated on this frame.